# Can Not Cast Timer to Array of Textboxes | Winform

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, c++-cli

I'm trying to implement a timer that runs every 10ms to determine if a field has been filled by the user. Essentially if a textbox (up to 10) is filled, a button will enable. If they fill, then delete the input, the timer will determine that and disable the button. That can be seen in the following:

```
private: System::Void StartBtn_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
int count = 0;

array < TextBox ^ > ^ textbox = { vPeak1, vPeak2, vPeak3, vPeak4, vPeak5, vPeak6, vPeak7, vPeak8, vPeak9, vPeak10 };
TextBox ^ current = (TextBox ^)sender;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (textbox[i]->Text != L"") count++;
    else count--;
}
```

this code works for a single textbox, however once I implemented the array of textboxes, the program crashes immediately with an exception at line 4. 'count' has a value of 0.

"'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Timer' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'.'"

Comment: Where is this code implemented exactly? You've posted code out of context. Where does `sender` come from?

Comment: @KenWhite I've added a bit more context. This is occurring within the Timer's Tick behavior. The sender is the text within the textbox that is being used elsewhere.

Comment: If it's happening in the Timer's Tick handler, then `sender` is the Timer, not a TextBox. You can't cast a Timer to a TextBox, clearly. `sender` is the `Object` that generated the event causing the code to be called, and that would be the `Timer`.

Comment: @KenWhite relatively new to c++-cli; I understand now. If you would like to post what you've said in the form of an answer, I'll give you the + rep. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the code you posted,

```
private: System::Void StartBtn_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
```

it would appear this is the Timer's `Tick` handler.  `sender` is the object that generated the event causing the handler to be called, so in this case
`sender` would be the Timer itself and not a TextBox.  You can't cast `sender` to a TextBox because it's not a TextBox, it's a Timer.

You can still accomplish the same thing without using `sender`, though, since you never use it anyway.

```
array < TextBox ^ > ^ textbox = { vPeak1, vPeak2, vPeak3, vPeak4, vPeak5, vPeak6, vPeak7, vPeak8, vPeak9, vPeak10 };
int count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (textbox[i]->Text != L"") count++;
}
// Test the final value of count here and do whatever you need
```